# How to achieve a flash/strobe effect?

Tags: jquery

I want to create an effect of camera flash similar to one from cuttherope.ie (the moment when you replay level) and I am stuck at the beginning: I want to use animate() with document to switch its background and font colors and then animate again removal of set properties. However even I can't get the first part working. The code's below:

http://jsfiddle.net/aM23f/3/

P.S: I know I can use jquery UI's effect("highlight") but because I am learning jQuery I want to achieve this effect by myself.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source for the highlight effect, there's a great deal to be learned from reading the jQuery code.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I've been trying but it's too complex for me at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use [`.animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) with the `background-color` property. [From the documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, `width`, `height`, or `left` can be animated but `background-color` cannot be, unless the [jQuery.Color()](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin is used).

One way to do a "flash" effect would be to combine [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/), [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/):

```
$("#experiment").click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut("fast").delay(25).fadeIn("fast");
});​
```

[**Live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Uxqf/)